# How to create always running redis client as Android ForegroundService?

Tags: android, flutter, redis

I have a challenge that involves push notifications without an internet connection.
I am using Redis pub/sub to receive messages on a local network. This works fine when the app is open or backgrounded. When the app is terminated, it cannot receive a push notification.
For more context, I am using [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package to show a notification when the app is backgrounded.

Comment: Even foreground services are not never ending in Android.  They will eventually be killed.  Having a never ending anything in Android isn't a thing.  You can receive FCM push notifications when terminated, but that's because the application doing the actual socket IO is part of the OS.  I suggest you rethink your architecture.  Unless this is only on devices you own, in which case you could possibly install Linux level daemons to do the actual IO.

Comment: FCM would be great but the device is not connected to the internet.

Comment: If it's only running on your hardware you could look into creating a custom OS image with a Linux service that does the redis connection and calls a registered BroadcastReceiver.  Or you could try to set that up even without the OS image.  But you're going to almost certainly need to drop from Flutter to a native language (java/kotlin), and you're going to have to learn a lot about how Android works at a level below what most devs do.

Comment: Or consider that Android may not be the right OS for you.  You may want a Linux box instead.